# 500 error when using sonata_media_type as a 1:N via a sonata_type_collection field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, sonata-media-bundle

I'm using SonataAdminBundle to administer the backend of a project I'm working on. In this case I'm wanting to add one-or-more images to "items". Here's the relevant bits of the entity

**src/My/Bundle/Entity/Item.php**

```
/**
 * Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="item")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Item
{
  /**
   * @var Media
   *
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", mappedBy="item")
   * ORM\JoinTable(name="item_media",
   *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   *   , inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="media_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
   * )
   */
  protected $media;
}
```

And now the relevant bits of the admin class:

**src/My/Bundle/Entity/Item.php**

```
class ItemAdmin extends Admin
{
  protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
  {
    $formMapper
        ->add('media', 'sonata_type_collection'
        , array(
              'required' => false
            , 'type' => 'sonata_media_type'
            , 'by_reference' => false
            , 'type_options' => array(
                  'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image'
                , 'context'  => 'default'
                , 'auto_initialize' => false
              )
          )
        , array(
              'edit' => 'inline'
            , 'inline' => 'table'
            , 'allow_delete' => true
            , 'sortable' => 'position'
        ))
    ;
  }
}
```

Now in the UI itself, when I click the <kbd>+ Add New</kbd> button, the AJAX response is a 500 error with the following message:

> Impossible to invoke a method ("trans") on a NULL variable ("") in
>   SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:CRUD:edit_orm_one_to_many.html.twig at
>   line 30

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I don't have much experience with the SonataAdminBundle, espeically with this type of inline-editing/creation of other entities.

Version Info:

- PHP 5.4.19
- Symfony 2.3.4
- SonataAdminBundle 2.2.3
- SonataMediaBundle
  2.2.3

Comment: Looks like you need "One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table" association and did it wrong. Check the official documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue seems to be related to [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonata-users/cq9M9dIXgeg) in the [sonata-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonata-users) google group.

The problem seems to be that the media-type's label isn't passed to the template which results in an error when invoking the translator/calling the `trans` method in the template here:

```
{{ nested_field.vars['sonata_admin'].admin.trans(nested_field.vars.label) }}
```

in [SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/edit_orm_one_to_many.html.twig](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/CRUD/edit_orm_one_to_many.html.twig#L30).

I suggest you first try to add a label to your form-type.

```
'label' => 'Media'
```

If that doesn't work you could fork the repository and clone it afterwards:

```
git clone https://github.com/yourusername/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle.git
```

then create a new branch using the 2.2.3 tag:

```
git branch bugfix-2.2.3 2.2.3
git checkout bugfix-2.2.3
```

now change `line 30` in `edit_orm_one_to_many.html.twig` to (or remove it completely which would result in the labels not being rendered at all)

```
{% if nested_field.vars.label %}
    {{ nested_field.vars['sonata_admin'].admin.trans(nested_field.vars.label) }}
{% endif %}
```

Afterwards commit your changes and ...

... either overwrite the tag (please note that tags should normally never be overwritten )

```
git commit
git tag -f 2.2.3
```

... or (**better**) create an alias in your `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "sonata/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "bugfix-2.2.3#<commit-sha> as 2.2.3"
```

then add this to your `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "http://github.com/yourusername/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle"}
],
```

afterwards run

```
composer update sonata/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
```

I'm not sure if it helps but the many-to-many support for inline-editing has been added in [this commit](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/pull/284/files). You could try changing your association to many-to-many and test wether the exception disappears.

If that doesn't work either please report back and i will dig deeper into this.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is thorough and looks like it has promise. I won't have a chance to check until later tonight when I'm at home, though.

Comment: Ok I tried adding the label in the with the builder/mapper (in `ItemAdmin::configureFormFields`) and that didn't work. However, when I modified the admin bundle as you suggested, that worked. But, it didn't get me terribly far because, as I think you observed with the linked pull request, the bundle doesn't support inline editing for a one-to-many. I'm going to try updating the bundle and then change my relationship to many-to-many.

Comment: okay please report back if changing to many-to-many works then i'll have a closer look at the differences to the one-to-many implementation and maybe come up with a PR.